# Java single-threaded multi-user chat program

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

So I'm working on this recreational project to learn more about java networking and so far every tutorial or documentation I've come across involves creating a new thread for each client connection to wait for input. I'm wondering if it's possible to handle the list of client connections with a single thread? I tried doing something like the following code but it didn't work.

```
while(true){
     for(Client c : list){
          DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(c.getSocket().getInputStream());
          if(dis.readLine()!=null){
               //Code
          }
          dis.close();
     }
}
```

Comment: Why the thread-aversion syndrome issues? Why not simply use background threads? Also, as far as I know, this isn't possible without multiple threads.

Comment: The fact that there is no real way to absolutely kill a thread from what I know

Comment: Just let the thread code run out. That will kill it. And also be sure to use a ThreadPool that will limit the number of threads.

Comment: So if say, in the run() method there is no loop and it's just a println(), when it reaches the end it just dies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible with a single thread using the NIO package.  This will allow you to set up non-blocking IO and multiplex across channels within your single thread.  It's not exactly trivial but there's a decent example [here](http://www.studytrails.com/java-io/non-blocking-io-multiplexing.jsp).

Your example above will block on the readLine() call until data is available on the Socket.  If one of your clients is waiting on data, the while loop will never proceed and you'll never service the other clients.